# Dropdown value does not insert into database after submit

Tags: php, mysql

The dropdown value does not insert into database (minit table) after submit. The dropdown values were populate from a different table (file table).

This is from addminit.php. It will receive input from user.

```
<p>File ID:<select class="" name="File ID">
        <?php
        while($rows = $filelist->fetch_assoc())
        {
          $f_id = $rows['file_id'];
          echo "<option value = '$f_id'>$f_id</option>";
        }
        ?>
</select></p>
```

This snippet is from minitadded.php. It will process the user input from addminit.php

```
<?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
          $data_missing = array();

          if(empty($_POST['file_id'])){
            $data_missing[] = 'File ID';
          }else{
             $f_id = trim($_POST['file_id']);
          }

          if(empty($_POST['minit_bil'])){
            $data_missing[] = 'Minit BIL';
          }else{
             $m_bil = trim($_POST['minit_bil']);
          }
          if(empty($_POST['minit_summ'])){
            $data_missing[] = 'Minit Summary';
          }else{
             $m_summ = trim($_POST['minit_summ']);
          }

          if(empty($data_missing)){
            require_once('databaseConnect.php');
            $query = "INSERT INTO minit (file_id,minit_bil, minit_summ) VALUES (?,?,?)";
            $stmt  = mysqli_prepare($dbConn,$query);

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sss",$f_id, $m_bil, $m_summ);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            $affected_rows = mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt);

            if($affected_rows == 1){
              echo 'Minit Entered';

              mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
              mysqli_close($dbConn);
            } else{
              echo 'Error Occured<br />';
              echo mysqli_error();
              mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
              mysqli_close($dbConn);
            }
```

After I sumbit the form from addminit.php. It will echo this code snippet.

```
          }else{
            echo 'You Need Enter The Following data<br />';

            foreach($data_missing as $missing){
              echo "$missing<br />";
            }
          }

        }
     ?>
```

Comment: try changing select tag name to `<select class="" name="file_id">`

Answer (score 0):

As fmsthird said, you're using POST to access a variable that doesn't exist. Either use $_POST["File ID"] to access the select variable, or change the name parameter of the select to "file_id"

Answer (score 0):

You are checking it on POST with the name **`file_id`**

**`if(empty($_POST['file_id'])){`**

So, try changing select tag name to **`<select class="" name="file_id">`**, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

'**File ID**'  *is not Equal to* '**file_id**'

> You used $_POST['file_id'] where 'file_id' should be the same as name attribute,
>   but in your HTML select tag the name attribute is 'File ID'

Do you understand, what the problem is?